# Android: fail to scale down bitmap object

Tags: android, bitmap, scale

The following code is taken from Android developers, with little changes:

```
private static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and
        // keeps both height and width larger than the requested height and
        // width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int reqWidth,
        int reqHeight) {

    int size = bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[size]);

    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
            // I set these manually because decodeStream set them to -1
    options.outHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
    options.outWidth = bitmap.getWidth();

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
            reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    // can the number of rows be wrong now?
    size = bitmap.getRowBytes() * options.outHeight;
    is = new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[size]);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
}
```

I have two problems:

1. When reading bitmap bounds in `decodeStream`, options.outHeight and options.outWidth are both set to -1, and I don't know why
2. The public method returns null when the bitmap is taken from my device's camera (hence read from a file), but works fine when bitmap is taken from an image that already existed on my phone (selected  from gallery).

Any ideas where the problem may be? thanks!

Comment: is your directory contain images??

Comment: how do you expect BitmapFactory to decode `is`, since there is nothing in it ? (`new byte[size]` is quite empty...)

Comment: use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html createScaledBitmap

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the image is somehow corrupted or not properly saved. In mist cases where bitmap is returned as null, this is the problem.

You could check the image in an image viewer on your desktop by copying the captured image to your desktop.